# WPF, MVVM: lag between the moment OnPropertyChanged is fired and UI refresh

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have implemented a plain vanilla MVVM apps. I have a datagrid bound to an `ObservableCollection`. When the database is refreshed, the collection is updated, the `OnPropertyChanged` is correctly fired but there is a lag before the UI is properly refreshed. I can tell that because when I debug, I can see that there is a few second between the moment the `OnPropertyChanged` is fired and the `get` accessor of the `ObservableCollection` is called. The lag does not seems to be correlated to the number of rows (ie 5 or 50 rows, it seems that there is the same lag).

Where can I start to find out where does this lag comes from ?

Code:
It is plain vanille MVVM hence:

```
private ObservableCollection<MyVar> _MyVars;
/// <summary>
/// List of pnl
/// </summary>
public ObservableCollection<MyVar> MyVars
{
    get
    {
        return _MyVars;
    }
    set
    {
        _MyVars = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyVars");
    }
}
```

The `ObservableCollection` `MyVars` is set by a call to a database. Basically what is happening is a lag between the call to `OnPropertyChanged("MyVars");` and the call to `return _MyVars;`. `MyVars` is the item source for a datagrid.
 Both in release and debug, the datagrid takes a few seconds to refresh and I found out that the lag is coming between the two calls I mentionned above. I can't put more code than that, I was just wondering If somebody had the same situation and which path did he/she took to debug and solve the problem.

Thanks,

Pierre

Comment: Can you post some of your code for us to look at, otherwise assumptions will be made which may lead you down the wrong path.

Comment: During debugging there's a lot going on so it might not be representative of what happens in an actual release build of the application. Is there also a lag when just running it without debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you re-assinging an ObservableCollection property? Just create it once and add / remove items as required.

```
private ObservableCollection<MyVar> _myVarsCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyVar>();

public IEnumerable<MyVar> MyVars => _myVarsCollection;

public void AddMyVar(MyVar myVar)
{
    _myVarsCollection.Add(myVar);
}

public void AddMyVars(IEnumerable<MyVar> myVars)
{
    foreach(var myvar in myVars)
        AddMyVar(myvar);        
}

public void RemoveMyVar(MyVar myVar)
{
    _myVarsCollection.Remove(myVar);
}
```

Even though _myVarsCollection is not public, any control bound to MyVars will detect that it implements INotifyCollectionChanged and will react accordingly when items are added / removed.

Comment: I was thinking that it is equivalent to add/remove items or to reassigned the whole collection altogether. Thanks I will try that.

Comment: Good thanks! This implemetation worked. Still I don't get the difference issue between my solution and yours. Any insight on some docs will be really appreciated.

Comment: If you refresh the list property, then the bound control has to completely re-create and re-draw all of the controls for each item - this is probably a good chuck of your lag. If you just add new items to the ObservableCollection then there's much less work to do.